# Можно ли выбрать элемент на SVG картинке?

Tags: c#, svg, xamarin

У меня есть SVG, который содержит электрическую схему.
Используя Xamarin я вывел схему на экран.

Но я не могу понять, можно ли в принципе выбрать отдельный элемент на схеме? 
Например, кликнуть по трансформатору и (произойдет какое-то событие в коде) и можно будет выделить данный элемент.
Если да, то можете дать ссылку на пример? Так как я гуглил, но видимо, плохо, так как не нашел.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конечно можно, svg это просто набор линий прямоугольников и прочих фигур которые сгруппированы особым образом, вот небольшой [`пример c codeopen`](https://codepen.io/jacobshapleski/pen/VaEObZ), он правда на JS но сути думаю не меняет. Вот [статья](http://css-live.ru/articles/karmannoe-rukovodstvo-po-napisaniyu-svg-glava-1-organizaciya-dokumenta.html) по поводу организации документов SVG.

```js
$('.shape').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  mthis = $(this);
  if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
    $(this).removeClass('selected');
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('selected');
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.container img, .container svg {
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  user-select: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.container svg .shape {
  fill: rgb(0,0,255);
  stroke: rgb(0,0,0);
  fill-opacity: 0;
  stroke-width: 2;
}

.container svg .shape.selected {
  fill-opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <img class="hotspot" src="https://66.media.tumblr.com/ec8bb434b97ed2e02a56579ca1606a53/tumblr_o09d7vVOI01qhy6c9o1_500.gif" width="500" height="500" alt="Pusheen">

  <svg width="500" height="500">
  <rect class="shape" x="55" y="88" width="172" height="237" />
  <circle class="shape" cx="249" cy="362" r="97" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke:rgb(0,0,0)"  />
  <polygon class="shape" points="334,143,332,157,347,169,365,166,366,182,407,210,414,243,409,265,384,288,341,284,303,263,279,241,259,214,265,186,284,161,308,146" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
</svg>

  <map name="pusheenmap">
  <area coords="55,88,227,325" shape="rect" href="#">
  <area coords="249,362,97" shape="circle" href="#">
  <area coords="334,143,332,157,347,169,365,166,366,182,407,210,414,243,409,265,384,288,341,284,303,263,279,241,259,214,265,186,284,161,308,146" shape="poly" href="#">
</map>

</div>
```

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/187261)

Comment: Поправил, теперь ответ не пропадет))